# Creating custom URI scheme using URI class

Tags: java, uri

I need to create a custom URI scheme for my project.
i.e

`urn:myprotocol:{p1}:{p2}:{p3}:{p4}` - opaque representation

`myprotocol://{p1}/{p2}/{p3}/{p4}` - hierarchical representation.

How can I add my scheme to Java URI class? Or, how can I make Java URI to understand my scheme, so I could use it in my code?

Concrete examples are welcome.

Comment: The scheme tag does not fit this question. It is used to refer to Scheme the language.

Comment: What do you expect the URI class to do with your scheme? A URI instance is just a representation of the URI and does not contain any scheme specific logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you need to create a new URI scheme?

It's considered bad practice to create implementation-specific schemes.

See:

- http://infomesh.net/2001/09/urischemes
- https://www.w3.org/TR/webarch/#URI-scheme
- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4395

Answer (score 1):

The Java API has a pretty good explanation of how to do that:
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URI.html

Without knowing what you are trying to do, I would use this constructor of URI:
URI(String scheme, String authority, String path, String query, String fragment)

Comment: That's what I was looking at. But it doesn't really fit the needs. Since it does nothing to verify the URI structure.