# include configs from ${HOME}/.app/someconfig.conf

Tags: config, typesafe-stack, typesafe

I need to include some properties file into my typesafe config, like

```
include ${user.HOME}"/.app/db-test.conf"
```

however parser complains:

```
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Parse: dev/application.conf: 47: include keyword is not followed by a quoted string, but by: '${'user.HOME'}'
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Parse: dev/application.conf: 47: include keyword is not followed by a quoted string, but by: '${'user.HOME'}'
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser$ParseContext.parseError(Parser.java:329)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser$ParseContext.parseError(Parser.java:325)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser$ParseContext.parseInclude(Parser.java:574)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser$ParseContext.parseObject(Parser.java:624)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser$ParseContext.parseValue(Parser.java:408)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser$ParseContext.parseObject(Parser.java:657)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser$ParseContext.parse(Parser.java:832)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser.parse(Parser.java:34)
```

How can I use system properties/environment variables in **include** statements?

Answer (score 1):

Can you do this manually in the code that loads your config?

```
Config baseConfig = ConfigFactory.load();
// Probably want error checking here.
Config testConfig = ConfigFactory.parseFile(
    new File(System.getenv("HOME") + "/.app/db-test.conf"));
// You may need to change your resolution order, depending on what you're doing in your 
// default config.
testConfig.resolve();
Config finalConfig = baseConfig.withFallback(testConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible out of the box (see https://github.com/typesafehub/config/issues/122 ).

However, you could write a custom `ConfigIncluder` if you are configuring an app with code you can modify, perhaps. See http://typesafehub.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/ConfigIncluder.html

You can also add a URL scheme to Java using standard Java mechanisms (see [Creating custom URI scheme using URI class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537255/creating-custom-uri-scheme-using-uri-class) )
and then use `include url("myscheme:whatever")`