# External configuration for Play 2 Framework

Tags: scala, tomcat, configuration, playframework-2.0, war

I have a custom configuration file for my database, and I want to externalize it when my Play project is packaged into a war.

I tried `javaOptions` in `build.sbt` with the `-DConfig.file` java command, but my file is not detected...

my line : `javaOptions in run += "-Dconfig.file=conf/database.conf"`

and my deployed war on a Tomcat server is :

`/mywar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

`/mywar/WEB-INF/lib/myplayproject.jar` (with other dependencies)

I put my conf file in lib directory : `/lib/conf/database.conf`

Where am I doing wrong ?

(based on this link : http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Detailed-Topics/Forking.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy your war on Tomcat, I don't see how sbt is involved, which may explain why your option is ignored.

Play is not really meant to be deployed as a war. I think the easiest thing for you would be to manually load the config file in your code via the typesafe config library.

Comment: So jvm commands can not work ? Play2War plugin is what I use to generate my war, it has explodedJar function, so it will resolve my problem but it doesn't work with the version I have.. And for typesafe config, this is what I use to parse my configuration file, and it can't access to it.

Answer (score 0):

When deploying to a container you aren't in control of the JVM process so you can't specify command line options to set system properties.

Your easiest approach here is probably to just rename your config file to reference.conf or application.conf. Those two names are auto-loaded by the configuration library from the classpath.

You could also edit reference.conf or application.conf to add `include "database.conf"` if you want to keep a separate file.

Otherwise you could manually load a config file, e.g. with `ConfigFactory.parseResource` to search the classpath.

In addition to including classpath resources you can include files and urls out of the box. Use the `include url("http://example.com")` or `include file("foo.conf")` syntax. By hand (in code) `ConfigFactory` can of course also parse urls and files.

If that isn't flexible enough, it's also possible to customize includes in two ways.

One is to create a custom ConfigIncluder http://typesafehub.github.io/config/latest/api/com/typesafe/config/ConfigIncluder.html

The other is to create a custom URL protocol in the usual Java way, see [Creating custom URI scheme using URI class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537255/creating-custom-uri-scheme-using-uri-class) and http://www.cooljeff.co.uk/2009/12/12/custom-url-protocols-and-multiple-classloaders/ for example. Then use include url("myproto:foobar")

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't resolve my problem : finally with this method my conf will be in the project jar, and I don't want that..

Comment: you can include (or parse) a file or URL, not just a classpath resource.